# Difference between Return and receive handlers Light Weight Filters

Tags: driver, ndis, filter-driver

I wanted to find out the differences between ReturnNetBufferListsHandler and ReceiveNetBufferListsHandler, When does NDIS call these call backs. I have light weight filter which will modify the receiving and send packets on the NIC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A LWF sits between a NIC driver and a protocol driver (like TCPIP).  The LWF has a chance to intercept both the transmit (Tx) & the receive (Rx) path.

**For Tx**
Whenever the protocol sends a packet, your filter's FilterSendNetBufferLists handler gets the packet.  When you're done with the protocol's packet, call NdisFSendNetBufferListsComplete to return it back to the protocol.

If you'd like to transmit a packet to the NIC driver, call NdisFSendNetBufferLists.  When the NIC driver is done with the Tx packet, your filter's FilterSendNetBufferListsComplete handler is called.

For a typical passthrough filter, then, the sequence of events looks like this:

1. FilterSendNetBufferLists 
 2. NdisFSendNetBufferLists
 3. FilterSendNetBufferListsComplete 
 4. NdisFSendNetBufferListsComplete

**For RX**
Whenever the NIC indicates a receive, your filter's FilterReceiveNetBufferLists handler gets the packet.  When you're done with the NIC's packet, call NdisFReturnNetBufferLists.  Except! if the special NDIS_RECIEVE_FLAG_RESOURCES flag is set.

If you'd like to indicate a receive to the protocol, call NdisFIndicateReceiveNetBufferLists.  When the protocol is done with your packet, your FilterReturnNetBufferLists handler is called.

For a typical passthrough filter, then, the sequence of events looks like this:

1. FilterReceiveNetBufferLists
 2. NdisFIndicateReceiveNetBufferLists
 3. FilterReturnNetBufferLists
 4. NdisFReturnNetBufferLists

Comment: Thanks Jeffery, It really helps me to understand the TX and RX paths for LWF.

Comment: Hi Jeffery, I have other question regarding Net Buffer Data, Waiting for your reply on this thread. [Link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41982378/net-buffer-list-re-packaging-light-weight-filter-driver)